# How to setup a reverse proxy using nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-14.04, docker

I am trying to get hostnames for my docker containers, and [since I can only use a reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988586/how-to-setup-hostnames-using-docker-compose) for that, I am trying to achieve exactly that with the help of nginx.

One docker container is a webservice that exposes the port 8080 to the my localhost.

So I can access the webserver via:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Instead I rather want to use:

```
http://webservice.local
```

Hence I added to my `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 webservice.local
```

I then installed nginx and added to the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     index index.html index.htm;

     # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
     server_name localhost;

     location / {
             # First attempt to serve request as file, then
             # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
             # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
             # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
     }


     location webservice.local {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080
     }
```

After reloading nginx I get the following the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when trying to open up `http://webservice.local` in my browser.

What did I do wrong? How can I setup the reverse proxy properly?

Comment: Show real config. Config in your post has syntax errors.

Comment: Also, I see ports 8080 and 9080. Which one is correct?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Both are, as I have two services I want to expose, yet wanted to boil the question down to use one example, going to fix it in question.

Comment: @AlexeyTen And this is the actual aconfig I am using. Where can I see the syntax error? Is there a way to validate the conf?

Comment: which OS, which nginx version is that

Comment: @sivann OS as tagged Ubuntu14.04 and nginx 1.4.6.

Comment: Try nginx -t  (checks configuration) Or nginx -t -c <base conf file>

Comment: @sivann Nice, thereby I get: `nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:13
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed` which begs the question to where it is correctly placed?

Comment: I think it's all wrong. I'll try to give you an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the correct syntax. Try something like that:

```
upstream myupstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=2s;
    keepalive 32;
}

location / {
     proxy_pass http://myupstream;
     proxy_redirect http://myupstream/ /;
}
```

something along these lines..

But if you just want to redirect port 8080 to 80 why not use a network utility like socat?

Then you should add virtualhosts in nginx for each upstream, and add those virtualhosts in DNS or /etc/hosts, which will all resolve to localhost.

Or you can just avoid the upstream and use virtualhosts like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myvirtualhost1.local;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myvirtualhost2.local;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
}
```

Comment: I tried your second approach but now I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: My bad, it was just a typo in my my `server_name`, this works great!