# How to disable timeout for nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration, timeout

On a local development machine, [I have a nginx reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/727314/how-to-setup-a-reverse-proxy-using-nginx) like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myvirtualhost1.local;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myvirtualhost2.local;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
}
```

Yet if I debug my application, the response may be delayed for an infinite amount of time, yet after 30 seconds I get:

`504 Gateway Time-out`

as a response.

How can I disable the timeout and have my reverse proxy wait forever for a response? And I like the setting to be global, so that I do not have to set it for each proxy.

Comment: Consider starting a background job and letting the user check its status later.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

It may not be possible to disable it at all, yet a feasible workaround is to increase the execution time. On a [nginx tutorial site](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/increase-script-execution-time/), it was written:

> If you want to increase time-limit for all-sites on your server, you
>   can edit main `nginx.conf` file:

```
vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

> Add following in http{..} section

```
http {
     fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
     proxy_read_timeout 300;
}
```

and reload nginx' config:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

I have used a rather large value that is unlikely to happen, i.e. `999999` or using [time units](https://nginx.org/en/docs/syntax.html), to one day via `1d`.

Beware that setting the value to `0` will cause a gateway timeout error immediately.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but a wild guess would be that OP asked for a way to disable the timeout and the reply just says how to increase it. So it's not an answer to the question OP asked.

Comment: @kb. It's funny as that I am the OP and just posted the most workable workaround as an answer, while waiting for a real solution ^^

Comment: Haha, I completely missed that you were OP. But your answer is the correct one, you could make it even more clear (for future googlers like me) that there is no way to disable it. =)

Comment: Thanks for the info about `0` not working! Note that [you can specify time units with readable suffixes](https://nginx.org/en/docs/syntax.html), so you could use a value like `1d`.

Comment: I have added both that and `proxy_connect_timeout 600;` to the nginx.conf file, but the timeout is still on 60 seconds. Anything else I should try?

Comment: When giving a solution please make it so that it applies generally, instead of your specific scenario. fastcgi_read_timeout is not always applicable, for example, Elastic Beanstalk apps on AWS.

Comment: I have the same issue as andreszs, exactly 60 seconds.

Comment: Update: adding `proxy_read_timeout` fixed the issue. @andreszs In case it's still relevant to you, could you confirm if that fixes it for you as well?

Comment: @BrandonMintern Thank you very much for the hint about the time units, I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been trying different approaches for the past few hours, my problem was with fastcgi_read_timeout. Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to set different timeout values for specific reverse proxies, rather than setting them globally?

Comment: I guess you've been downvoted because you should **never** touch `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. In case of update, this file might be erased, and anyway it's a bad practice. Read the file carefully and you'll see in the `http` section, it includes `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`. So, this is where you should put your own "custom" configuration: create a file, like `/etc/nginx/conf.d/global_custom.conf` (or whatever name you want), and put your directives there. You can find so many misleading informations on the web...

Comment: Maybe you didn't know but you can change globally (`http {...}`), or by virtual host (`server {...}`), or even by URLs (`location {...}`).

Answer (score 41):

It is possible to increase the timeout for nginx, to add to @k0pernikus 's answer, the following can be added to your location block:

```
        location /xyz {
         proxy_read_timeout 1800;
         proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
         proxy_send_timeout 1800;
         send_timeout 1800;
        }
```

Here 1800 is in seconds.

After changing the config, verify the syntax with:

```
nginx -t -c /some/path/nginx.conf
```

Then reload nginx with:

```
nginx -s reload
```

Comment: about each timeout http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout

Comment: is there anyway to set a variable as 1800 and then assign that variable, I tried using set, but it didnt work

Comment: @MaxCarroll, I don't think config files generally support variables. Set wouldn't work as it is not bash.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using AWS, and Load Balancer, you should edit Idle timeout. I think default is 60 seconds

Comment: I understand _why_ this was down voted but maybe if the answer was updated to explain its use case, it would be more useful.
Although this doesn't go to answer the OP, it is something useful to consider if you are using ELB as there is a limit on how long they will keep a connection open also.

Comment: @doz87 yes, it's just something for consideration

Comment: This is really worth checking especially on my case that working with Magento under the AWS. Good point @szeljic

Comment: Thanks bro, this works for me since I use AWS load balancer for distributing to my EC2 instance

Comment: This deserves all the upvotes - any AWS users will still be limited to 60 seconds regardless of their NGINX settings without this

Comment: This was something I ran into. I needed to step back and think about all the components in my stack before I realised the LB was the reason for the timeout.

Comment: "idle timeout" : what field would that be, and where is it?

Comment: @foo it's on the LoadBalancer page on AWS. the Description tab and the Attributes section. Idle timeout.

Answer (score 12):

I've been fighting with nginx 502 timeout error and could not solve the issue. However, it happened to be gunicorn causing the timeout error. So you might also need to check your fastcgi settings.

For gunicorn it's:

```
gunicorn wsgi:application --timeout 300
```