# Why is my websocket connection gets closed in 60 seconds?

Tags: nginx, docker

I have an Angular web application proxied by nginx. There is a websocet functionality in the application and the relevant section looks as follows:

```
  location /ws {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://websocket.server:9090/ws;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
```

nginx is dockerized and is run on my machine by `docker-compose` in a custom built image:

```
FROM node:alpine as node-build
WORKDIR /app
ADD ...
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
ADD nginx.conf ./
COPY --from=node-build /app/... /usr/share/nginx/html
```

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
    - 4200:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

There is nothing else in nginx.conf except few other locations:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name frontend;
  location / {...}
  location /ws {...}
  location /api {...}
}
```

I use Docker Desktop for Mac, v.3.2.1.

It works fine except that any connection to `/ws` gets closed in exactly 60 seconds, which looks like a timeout set somewhere. What should I check in order to fix it?

**UPDATE**: for what it worth, the issue does not happen if I access the application through http://localhost:4200, but does happen if I access by the host name or domain name.

Comment: exactly same problem here

Answer (score 6):

I google the thing a bit and found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/993559/555276) regarding nginx's timeouts. By doing some tests I discovered that the couple of parameters

```
    proxy_read_timeout 1800;
    proxy_send_timeout 1800;
```

just does the trick.

Comment: your trick did`nt work